# PrimeFaces - Dynamic menuItem

Tags: jsf-2, primefaces

Considering the following code, it displays a table with one column and a filter to display the active/inactive records.
How can I disable the menuitem 'Inactive' based on the value selected in the filter? In other words if the the filter value is 'inactive', the 'Inactivate' menu should be disabled.

```
            <p:contextMenu for="ratingScaleTable" id="RsContextMenuId">
                <p:menuitem value="Edit" update=":templateForm:tabView, :templateForm:dirtyFlag"    icon="ui-icon-search" action="#{ratingScaleBK.edit}" />
                <p:menuitem id="inactivate" value="Inactivate"  icon="ui-icon-close" action="#{ratingScaleBK.inactivate}" disabled="#{ratingScaleBK.selectedRatingScale.active==0}" />
                <p:menuitem value="Activate" update=":templateForm:tabView" icon="ui-icon-close" action="#{ratingScaleBK.activate}"/>
                <p:menuitem value="View Archive" update=":templateForm:tabView" icon="ui-icon-close"/>
            </p:contextMenu>                        

            <p:dataTable id="ratingScaleTable" widgetVar="tableWidget"
                value="#{ratingScaleBK.ratingScaleList}" var="item1" 

                selectionMode="single"
                selection="#{ratingScaleBK.selectedRatingScale}"
                rowKey="#{item1.name}"
                rendered="#{not empty ratingScaleBK.ratingScaleList}"
                filteredValue="#{ratingScaleBK.filteredRatingscale}">

                <p:ajax event="rowSelect" process="ratingScaleTable" listener="#{ratingScaleBK.edit}"  update=":templateForm:tabView, :templateForm:dirtyFlag, :templateForm:tabView:RsContextMenuId " />


                <p:column id="activeCol" filterBy="#{item1.active}"
                    filterOptions="#{ratingScaleBK.activeOptions}"
                    filterMatchMode="exact" width="30">
                    <h:outputText value="#{item1.active}" />
                </p:column>
            </p:dataTable>
```

Right now this code doesn't work, the contextMenu is never updated on rowSelect (the menu item 'Inactive' is always enabled). I guess the right click event on a specific row to display the menu doesn't really trigger the rowSelect event even if the row gets highlighted. 
What is the proper way to do that?

Answer (score 2):

I ended up using this solution from [PF forum](http://forum.primefaces.org/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=26813#p93374):

```
<p:contextMenu for="ratingScaleTable" id="RsContextMenuId"  widgetVar="ctxMenu" beforeShow="return true;">

<p:dataTable id="ratingScaleTable" widgetVar="tableWidget"
...
  <p:ajax event="rowSelect" process="ratingScaleTable" listener="#{ratingScaleBK.edit}"  update=":templateForm:tabView, :templateForm:dirtyFlag, :templateForm:tabView:RsContextMenuId" />
  <p:ajax event="contextMenu" update=":templateForm:tabView:RsContextMenuId" oncomplete="ctxMenu.show(currentEvent);"/>
```

and the associated JavaScript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var currentEvent;
  $(document).ready(function() {
  PrimeFaces.widget.ContextMenu.prototype.show = function(e) {
     //hide other contextmenus if any
     $(document.body).children('.ui-contextmenu:visible').hide();

     if(e) {
        currentEvent = e;
     } 

     var win = $(window),
     left = e.pageX,
     top = e.pageY,
     width = this.jq.outerWidth(),
     height = this.jq.outerHeight();

     //collision detection for window boundaries
     if((left + width) > (win.width())+ win.scrollLeft()) {
        left = left - width;
     }
     if((top + height ) > (win.height() + win.scrollTop())) {
        top = top - height;
     }

     if(this.cfg.beforeShow) {
        this.cfg.beforeShow.call(this);
     }

     this.jq.css({
        'left': left,
        'top': top,
        'z-index': ++PrimeFaces.zindex
     }).show();

     e.preventDefault(); 
  };
});
</script>
```

Comment: I have tried this solution but I get the following error: treeMenu is not defined. But it is defined as widgetVar's name of the context menu. Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

Try it with the *contextMenu* event:

```
<p:contextMenu for="ratingScaleTable" id="RsContextMenuId" widgetVar="ctxMenu">
    ...
</p:contextMenu>

<p:dataTable ... > 
    ...
    <p:ajax event="contextMenu" process="ratingScaleTable" listener="#{ratingScaleBK.edit}"  update=":templateForm:tabView, :templateForm:dirtyFlag, :templateForm:tabView:RsContextMenuId" oncomplete="PF('ctxMenu').show();" />
    ...
</p:dataTable>
```